# add password validation while updating password

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following validation for a user in rails project

```
validates :password,   presence: true, format: { with: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, multiline: true }, on: :create
```

How can I validate the password in devise_token_auth password update

Comment: This will validate password and will not allow saving if validation fails, this looks fine. So what exactly is the question ?

Comment: This will validate only when a user is created. right?

Comment: @PamioSolanky I need to validate it when updating the password as well

Comment: validate works alwys for both create and update. To be precise, it works before saving a record. Why don’t you try it yourself. You will understand it better

Comment: I have checked it and it worked only while creating new user as it is specified in validate statement 

'on: :create'

Comment: remove `on: :create`, it will work for updates also :)

Comment: but in user props update api there is no password field. As password is required validation, when I add :update or remove :create it will generate a validation error in the api

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153735/discussion-between-pamio-solanky-and-cr7).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There you go:

```
validates :password,   presence: true, format: { with: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, multiline: true }, if: :password_validation

def password_validation
  new_record? || password_digest_changed?
end
```

This will trigger the validation on password in two cases:

1. When it's a new record.
2. When the password change is attempted.

Assuming you are using `has_secure_password`, it gives `password` and `password_confirmation` as attributes, and `password_digest` as the field. Rails exposes `_changed?` method to check if the given attribute has changed ([is dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html)) (and not persisted yet).

```
u = User.last
u.email = 'foobar@foobar.com'
u.email_changed? #=> true
u.save #=> true
u.email_changed? #=> false
```

Comment: password_digest_changed? is that a method we need to add in the user model

Comment: no. assuming you are using has_secure_password, you won't need to add anythign else. added more details in answer above.

Comment: removed `return if !persisted?` since you need it in case of new record as well.